# IST time zone not getting parsed

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdateformatter

I have a string **Tue Feb 23 10:12:48 IST 2014**, I want to get the NSdate object form this. I am using below code snippet

```
    NSString * buildTime = @"Tue Feb 23 10:12:48 IST 2014";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:buildTime ];
```

Every time I am getting nil value to **date** variable. If I am changing IST to GMT in build time then NSDate is perfectly coming. Can any one correct me where I am doing mistake in this.

Comment: Try using `VVV` instead of `ZZZ`. I found another post that indicated that would work for the `IST` timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But VVV is also not working

Answer (score 1):

**Use small 'zzz' instead of 'ZZZ',**

```
NSString * buildTime = @"Tue Feb 23 10:12:48 IST 2014";
NSLocale *indianEnglishLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:indianEnglishLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:buildTime];
NSLog(@"date %@",date);
NSLog(@"string %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: good code snippet ; in case you want to change the timeZone, add it after dateformatter , '[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];'

Comment: This is perfectly working, Can you tell me in place of IST tomorrow PST is coming then what would be the parameter for initWithLocaleIdentifier:, This is just my sub question...

Comment: You can try research for PST - America/LA. check locale identifiers by printing [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers] and use appropriate.