# issue with converting string to date using nsdataformatter - returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using NSDateFormatter to convert a string date to a NSDate.

This works.

```
                   NSDateFormatter * formatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [formatDate setDateFormat:@"ddMMMyyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz"];
                    dateStr = @"01Jul2019 08:15:00 PM EDT";
                    tempInv.time_of_purchase = [formatDate dateFromString:dateStr];
```

This does not work and returns nil ???

```
                   NSDateFormatter * formatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [formatDate setDateFormat:@"ddMMMyyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz"];
                    dateStr = @"01Jul2019 08:15:00 PM IST";
                    tempInv.time_of_purchase = [formatDate dateFromString:dateStr];
```

only difference is the TIME ZONE.  In the 2nd one its IDT.  note: it seems PST works fine. EST works fine. but others do not.

can anyone shed some light on this ? and why nil would be getting returned.  note: the iphone it is running on is EDT.

Comment: See [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsdateformatter+IST). `IST` is ambiguous.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846879/nsdateformatterist-not-recognised?r=SearchResults&s=1|67.1353 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084980/nsdateformatter-doesnt-show-time-zone-abbreviation-for-asia-kolkata-for-the?r=SearchResults&s=3|52.9345 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746798/ist-time-zone-not-getting-parsed?r=SearchResults&s=4|51.9828 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449004/nsdateformatter-geting-null?r=SearchResults&s=5|49.7545

Comment: It's always best to avoid timezone abbreviations since they are not unique. Use full timezone names or offsets.